# Django retrieve extra info using a single query

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I have a question about these models:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    #Some fields ....


class LikePost(models.Model):
    # Author info
    author = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name='post_likes')
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name="likes")
    dateJoined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

when I retrieve the Post's info I need also to know if the current user (`request.user`) has already made a likeAction on the current Post.

I would to make this efficiently (if is possible) using a single query when I take the details of the Post.

At the moment I use this query:

```
Post.objects.annotate(likes_count=Count('likes')).get(pk=pk)
```

I use `.annotate()` to retrieve the count of the likes...

Can I add something about `.annotate()` or `.extra()` to know if the user has already made a likeAction on the current Post?

Comment: Yes you can. Just use `select_related`, `.annotate` or `.extra`.

Comment: Ok, thx... but is possible to add a code example for this models?

Comment: How is https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#select-related not enough?

Answer (score 0):

That could be a problem.

The Django ORM will, in my experience, at most join any particular table into a query once. This is useful for applying multiple conditions to the same related data (this is often quite useful).  What you need is two separate joins of some related data; one where you count all the likes, and one where you are only concerned with likes from a particular user. What Django would do is counting only the likes of the particular user, if you did something like

```
Posts.objects.filter(likes__user_id=user.id).annotate(
    likes_count=Count('likes')).get(pk=pk)
```

you risk a `DoesNotExist` exception if the user didn't like the particular `Post`.  If the user did like the particular post `likes_count` would only count the number of like relations between the particular user and the particular post. I believe this is not what you need.

You can do all this in one query, though, but you will load a bit more data than otherwise required;

```
post = Posts.objects.select_related('likes').get(pk=pk)
post.likes_count = len(post.likes)
user_already_likes_this = any(like.user_id == user.id for like in post.likes)
```

Now you have to benchmark the extra data approach and the two queries approach.

I am convinced you should just use the two queries approach, because each http request probably result in 15 or more queries already, so one extra doesn't hurt too much, and it scales much better as the number of likes grows.

Answer (score 0):

```
result = (Post.objects.annotate(likes_count=Count('likes'))
    .extra(
        select={
            'already_liked': (
                "select count(*) from {app_name}_likepost "
                "where {app_name}_likepost.author_id = {uid} "
                "and {app_name}_likepost.post_id = {pid}"
            ).format(
                uid=request.user.id,
                pid=pk,
                app_name=your_django_app_name,
            ),
        }
    )
    .get(pk=pk)
)
result.already_liked # 1 if action performed, 0 if not
```

However, this will be subquery, and some databases may not support this.
Also [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#extra) recommend to avoid such approach if possible. Though to fetch all needed data in one query you'll require this (or build whole sql query manually).

As django docs state, `select_related` won't work on backward foreign_key relation, and `prefetch_related` will actually do one more query, so it will be two queries in total (and in addition to that - it will load much more unrequired data, like all LikePost records).